# SQL - Deduct column value until non-negative value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms, acid

I working on a table which there is an int column that will get deducted when some event happens. The value is predetermined and cannot goes below zero.

There will be a lot of concurrent SQL transaction to claim the value from the database. It just a counter, like how the concert ticket is reserved.

Currently, my logic cannot guarantee that it stays above 0 in an efficient manner (Select before update cannot guarantee that :( ). Is there a trick to enforce this business rule?

If the value is insufficient, the transaction should not pass.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1 - use unsigned

```
ALTER TABLE events MODIFY event_count INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
```

Attempting to reduce below 0 will error.

Solution 2 - using the query

```
UPDATE events SET event_count=event_count-1 WHERE event_id={X} AND event_count > 0
```

Look at the rows affected to see if this took place.

Comment: UNSIGNED seem to be the easiest if an error is indeed thrown, I will try this later. Thanks for the tips

Comment: Second solution might not work because the value is likely become negative when concurrent transaction is doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can explore CHECK constraint of MySQL. It will ensure that column value will never go below zero also you will not be required to validate the counter using SQL code.

Sample Table Def :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS events (
    event_count DECIMAL(10 , 2 ) NOT NULL CHECK(cost >= 0),
    price DECIMAL (10,2) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: MySQL parses but does not enforce check constraints.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support check constraint, else will be easy task

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you neeed some kind of locking mechanism.

That functionality is available in MySQL :

- InnoDB tables implement row-level locking - see [this documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html)
- ISAM only provide table-level locking

Comment: Probably best to save this form of solution for significantly harder constraints or those that involve multiple SQL statements.

Comment: Ya, there might be hundreds of concurrent transaction, my update query need to span multiple table, dont think will work efficiently

Comment: @user1622801 well as far as concerns that’s pretty much the type of use case for which locking is meant... But for sure this required thorough testing. Just make sure that the necessary index exists if you want row-level locking